# Adding Files view on Ambari 1.7.0: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: ambari

I'm trying to add views on Ambari 1.7.0.

For the Files view that is available here: https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/contrib/views/files

I get an error after trying to launch an instance of the view:

> 500 HdfsApi connection failed. Check "webhdfs.url" property

With the following Stack Trace (just the first lines):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2415)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2428)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
```

I just add the following property during the configuration of the view:

> webhdfs.url webhdfs://mycluster1:50070

I'm not sure but perhaps it's an issue during the building part like version conflict, i'm working on that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

What is the value you have used for WebHDFS url in file view instance ?

Is your cluster Namenode HA enabled ? If yes , try to use url as webhdfs://:50070
If not HA enabled the use webhdfs://:50070

If none works use direct data node dfs address as webhdfs://:50070

Comment: I don't see any difference between the webhdfs://:50070 urls you provided above for both HA and non HA.